# Can't install React using npx in vs code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm getting this error while installing React using npx in vs code

````
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hpw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-15T09_00_22_661Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.```


Can anyone tell how to fix it ?
````

Comment: What command have you typed? Try `npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: I tried this command only

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
npx create-react-app@latest app-name
```